# Is it possible to get the screenwidth in pixels, without units, with CSS's calc()?

Tags: css

I'm trying to calculate a `zoom`-value using `calc()`, but since `zoom` only takes either a no-units value or a percentage value, I'm having a hard time getting what I want using `calc()`.

Am I doomed to using JavaScript for this, or is there a way?

I want to calculate the ratio between an element on the page and the screen width minus a set width, so the calculation would be `(screenWidth - setWidth) / elementWidth`. I can get `setWidth` and `elementWidth` as plain numbers, but I can't figure out a way to get `screenWidth` other than `100vw`, and that just ends up being `(100vw - 300) / 900)` => `-200vw / 900` => `-0.222222vw` which, as you  might guess, is not what I want.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `vw/px/%` are interchangeable as long as you define them. Someone may want to correct me on this? E.g - you could have `(100vw - 300px) / 900px` (not sure why you'd divide by 900px though..)

Comment: The *actual* value returned by calc() can differ across browsers if I remember correctly, depending on the arguments you give to it. Most often in pixels, though. But getting a *unitless* value from calc() is impossible I think.